# How to read .yaml file in Github repository and publish content to Github page

Tags: javascript, github, yaml, github-pages, github-api

I'm trying to set up a Github page from my enterprise private repository. There is a yaml file containing metadata of a list of application in the repository including application name, description, and miscellaneous. I only want to publish the name and description to the Github page and later I would create a search bar to find the available application name in the repository. 
The Github page is backed by a index.html file inside docs folder in my repository. Is there any solution for me to achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Github Pages serves only static files, but you can use Jekyll to generate those static files based on your data. To do that, place your YAML file in `_data` and then generate your HTML with Liquid templates, as described [here](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/datafiles/). General information about using Jekyll with Github Pages is available [here](https://help.github.com/articles/using-jekyll-as-a-static-site-generator-with-github-pages/).

For the search bar, you'd need to use client-side JavaScript. Just group the element for each application with a `class` so that you can query them with JS, then show or hide them based on the searched term(s). You could also generate static JSON file that contains all information with Liquid from your data and then load and process that client-side with JS. Finally, you could serve the YAML file itself to the client and load it using js-yaml.

Comment: As far as I know, js-yaml is a library for js. Is this possible to install any additional library for js on Github and run it on the static pages?

Comment: You just drop the `.js` file to GitHub and then reference it. Some libraries offer hosted versions of their minimized `.js` file you can include directly without adding them to your repo. I am not a JS dev and don't know all the details.